# Countdown script in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I've written this [little countdown script](https://github.com/Ralt/ralt.github.com/blob/master/school/countdown.js) to count until the end of our school days.

Now, that was written quickly, badly remembering modulo from a few years ago, and I don't think that's very optimized.

I thought about updating only the seconds and check if it needs to update the minute too, etc. But it wouldn't be accurate as `setTimeout` is not (depending if the browser lags, etc).

```
(function() {
    //the variable block here seems kinda weird, but whatever toots your horn
    var el = document.getElementById('countdown'),
        endDate = new Date('March 30, 2012 18:10:00'),
        curDate,
        diff,
        days,
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds,
        tmp,
        countdown,
        //added Math.floor. this is already a shortcut, might as well make it a double one
        pad = function(number) { return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + Math.floor(number) },

        //calculate these constants once, instead of over and over
        minute = 60 * 1000,
        hour = minute * 60,
        day = hour * 24

    ;(function tick() {
        curDate = new Date()
        //you want the absolute value of this, not of individual calculations using this
        diff = Math.abs(new Date(curDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime()))
        days = diff / day

        tmp = diff % day
        hours = tmp / hour

        tmp = tmp % hour
        minutes = tmp / minute

        tmp = tmp % minute
        seconds = tmp / 1000

        //parseInt was redundant
        countdown = pad(days) + ':' + pad(hours) + ':' + pad(minutes) + ':' + pad(seconds)

        if ( 'textContent' in el ) {
            el.textContent = countdown
        }
        else {
            el.innerText = countdown
        }

        //dont't use arguments.calle, it's deprecated
        //simply use a named function expression
        setTimeout(tick, 1000)
    }())
}())​
```

About the semicolons missing: it is a deliberate choice as I find this more readable (the `;` right before the `(function()` is because it is the only edge case where the semicolon insertion doesn't work correctly).

Comment: Some cool stuff going on here, never thoughts of using arguments.callee like that to avoid a named function. though mdn does seem to recommend against it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee#A_bug_after_the_deprecation_of_arguments.callee.3F

Comment: Yep, it is deprecated :-). I just posted a reviewed version by @Zirak. Not sure if I should close the question or not.

Comment: you wanan get really slick? `el[('textContent' in el) ? 'textContent' : 'innerText'] = countdown` Also though, you can cache the result of that calculation

Comment: Good point, I should definitely cache the result of this.

Comment: `setInterval()` is far more optimized and is often recommended over `setTimeout()`. There is an awesome article by John Resig (inventor of jQuery and co-author of *Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja*). The book is amazing, I recommend it to everyone too! [John Resig's blog](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole code can be reduced to this.

```
/* secsToDHMS()
 * Author Gary Green
 * http://stackoverflow.com/users/63523/gary-green
 */
function secsToDHMS(s)
{
  var x = [86400, 3600, 60, 1],z,i=-1;
  while (z=x[++i])
        x[i] = ("0" + parseInt(s / z,10)).slice(-2),
        s %= z;

    return x.join(':');
};

(function() {

    var currentDate      = new Date();
    var endDate          = new Date('March 30, 2012 18:10:00');
    var secsToGo         = (new Date(endDate - currentDate)).getTime() / 1000;
    var countdownElement = document.getElementById('countdown');

    var timer = setInterval(function() {

        if (--secsToGo < 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            return;
        }

        countdownElement.innerHTML = secsToDHMS(secsToGo);

    }, 1000);

})();
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/xg63V/4

---

Compressed version **311 bytes**

```
(function(){var d=(new Date(new Date("March 30, 2012 18:10:00")-new Date)).getTime()/1E3,
f=document.getElementById("countdown"),g=setInterval(function(){if(0>--d)clearInterval(g);
else{for(var a=d,b=[86400,3600,60,1],c,e=-1;c=b[++e];)b[e]=("0"+parseInt(a/c,10)).slice(-2),
a%=c;f.innerHTML=b.join(":")}},1E3)})();​
```

Comment: Your version looks somehow nice, but I don't like the use of `setInterval` or `innerHTML`. The `secsToDHMS` function is really nice though!

Answer (score 0):

First question - your countdown is "symmetric", it does not care if current date is past the end date. Is it on purpose?

Define constants to avoid "magic numbers": `var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24` etc

May be it is better to calculate `diff = Math.abs(curDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime())` without new object construction, and you do not need to invoke Math.abs anymore (see the question above).

Then, `days = Math.floor(diff / ONE_DAY)` to ensure integer number. Same for other calculations.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, they're already used in @Zirak's version :). The symmetric part of the countdown is okay, a simple if check will solve this.